# Multer validation with joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, joi

I've created an endpoint to post and upload a csv file for processing in Node. It works fine but I'm trying to figure out how to validate a few things before uploading the file.

A sample request would be:

```
{
    "test_doc": "/path/to/file/test.csv"
    "offset": [0,1]
}
```

I want the form to require "test_doc" and only accept csv files and have "offset" be optional

The schema for the "offset" works but I'm unsure how to validate the file with multer as well, especially before uploading it.

Sample code below

```
const upload = multer({ dest: "/tmp" });

router.post("/", upload.single("test_doc"), async (req, res) => {
    const schema = joi.object().keys({
        offset: joi.array().items(joi.number().min(-60).max(60)).min(1).max(2)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fileFilter method to validate file types in Multer. The fileFilter method is a built-in method which comes with Multer middleware:

```js
const upload = multer({
    dest: "/tmp",
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      if (file.mimetype == "text/csv" && file.fieldname === "test_doc") {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
        return cb(new Error('Invalid upload: fieldname should be test_doc and .csv format '));
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up finding this but ran into a problem where csv made by excel didn't come back with a mimetype of csv. Also, how would I validate the fieldname of "test_doc"? Is it possible to validate the optional "offset" field before uploading the file as well?

Comment: I updated the answer with an additional condition into fileFilter. for offset you can add your existing validation in the fileFilter method as well as you have access to the request (text field are accessible like in the request body : `req.body.offset`,

Comment: I'm still having some problems. req.body is empty inside of fileFilter so offset is not there. Also, fileFilter doesn't seem to run at all if the parameter name is not "test_doc" and just sends back an error, I think this is to do with upload.single("test_doc"). Is there also a way to send an error back with status code and just an error message instead of everything cb returns?

Comment: You would need to ask another question for that, this would be a complete different answer.

Comment: The only way I can validate offset is after file is uploaded and haven't found another way, I don't know why I need to ask another question for validating the parameter name as it was in my initial question. fileFilter is not run at all when supplying a different fieldname in JSON request in this example.

Comment: I was talking about a custom error handler to handle errors generated by Multler